Hide schema in postgis database in qgis
Suppose I have a postgres database "A", and this database "A" contains schema A, B, and public. How to hide schema B inside qgis when user connects to database "A" through postgis?

Just don't give the user permission to use that schema. Use REVOKE: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-revoke.html And you might want to check all permission since a user would have this permission by default. Unless you changed the defaults.
